# Register New Global Scope in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, global-scope

I want to register a new global scope in Laravel 5.7 but I got the following error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_PARSE)
>        syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC)

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * Anonymous scope
    */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('authenticated', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('id_user', '=', Auth::id());
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using laravel 5.7 PHP 7.2

Comment: It is usually something in the code prior to this which is causing the error which we can't see.

Comment: It's a Syntax error like it says. Check your recent workings and find the syntax error.

Comment: The codes which you shared in the post does not have any error/syntax error. You did somewhere else the syntax error so you can be found it with try-catch code blocks in the "public/index.php"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add an anonymous global scope which is absolutely fine but you need to use Eloquent\Builder for that approach to work (this doesn't seem to fit your exact error, however, you will need this) so add the following to your class and see if the error changes!!

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

Comment: Works perfect !!

Answer (score 1):

The docs for global scopes in 5.7 suggest you should implement them rather differently than you are dong here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes.

You need to implement the `Scope` class and then create an `apply()` method.

Comment: I don't typically use scopes in this manner, however, it is perfectly legit approach.  I tend to generate the global scope (probably like you).  He is using anonymous global scope.

Answer (score -1):

Use this package for generate and load global scopes into laravel

https://github.com/limewell/laravel-make-extender

`php artisan make:scope UserScope`

`php artisan make:scope ActiveScope`

`php artisan make:scope AgeScope`

etc...

Comment: Why is there a need to add one more package for something which is part of Laravel?